# TextBox Style issue for Panorama with dark image background

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 panorama application that uses a dark image for the panorama's background. The issue is when the device is set to light theme. The issue root cause is the Focus state transition animation for the TextBox sets the background color to transparent.

Since my panorama is always dark I'd like my textbox to always be white background.

First attempt set textbox background to white.
FAIL: transition changes background back to transparent when textbox gets focus.

Next attempt programmatically set textbox background to white on gotfocus.
FAIL: transition changes background back to transparent when textbox gets focus.

Next attempt override control template and change transition.
FAIL: never could get this happy with WP7, not sure if I used right version

Next attempt override control template using Blend 4.
FAIL: might have missed something but every state looked correct.

I see where lots of others are having this same problem but no here's exactly what you need to do so you don't trip up some minor detail.

If you can help us with a solution please do share.

---

Here's what I tried with Blend 4.

Opened my project in Blend 4, selected my textbox, right-clicked on it, chose Edit Template, and then Edit a Copy.

Here's where I'm not exactly sure what I need to do.

I went to FocusStates, and selected Focused. What I see in the preview pane looks like what I want. A nice textbox with a white background.

I look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx and I see there is a storyboard animation for the various FocusStates and I figure in WP7 there must be one that makes textboxes have a transparent background when they have focus in the light theme.

My goal of making my textbox have a white background since I have a panorama with a dark background image has proven difficult to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path with this retemplating the control in blend. You can control formating of each constituent component of the control and for each state.

If you're still having trouble with this, post your resulting xaml for the TextBox in your question once you've made the changes.

**Re your edit:** Focused -> Grid-EnabledBorder-Background uses static resource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush. You can change this to a local value then choose your colour.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. At least I can focus my efforts now. I still seem to be missing a step somewhere.